# Why are PackageInstaller.getSessionInfo results inconsistent?

Tags: android, android-studio, packageinstaller

Below is my code that uses PackageInstaller to install an APK I've downloaded from my server.

```
public static final String ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".INSTALL_COMPLETE";
private void installApk(String apkFilePath) {
    try {
        // Create package manager installation params
        final PackageInstaller pkgInstaller = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
        PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);

        // Create session callback for monitoring progress
        pkgInstaller.registerSessionCallback(new PackageInstaller.SessionCallback() {
            static final String PKG_LOG_TAG = "pkg-install-status";

            @Override
            public void onCreated(int sID) {
                Log.e(PKG_LOG_TAG, "Session created: " + sID);
                PackageInstaller.SessionInfo sessionInfo = pkgInstaller.getSessionInfo(sID);
                if (sessionInfo != null) {
                    Log.e(PKG_LOG_TAG, "Installing package name: " + sessionInfo.getAppPackageName());
                }
                else {
                    Log.e(PKG_LOG_TAG, "Session does not exist: " + sID);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBadgingChanged(int sID) {
                Log.e(PKG_LOG_TAG, "Badging Changed: " + sID);
            }

            @Override
            public void onActiveChanged(int sID, boolean active) {
                Log.e(PKG_LOG_TAG, "Active Changed: " + sID + ", active=" + active);
                PackageInstaller.SessionInfo sessionInfo = pkgInstaller.getSessionInfo(sID);
                if (sessionInfo != null) {
                    Log.e(PKG_LOG_TAG, "Installing package name: " + sessionInfo.getAppPackageName());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int sID, float progress) {
                Log.e(PKG_LOG_TAG, "Progress changed: " + sID + ", progress=" + progress);
                PackageInstaller.SessionInfo sessionInfo = pkgInstaller.getSessionInfo(sID);
                if (sessionInfo != null) {
                    Log.e(PKG_LOG_TAG, "Installing package name: " + sessionInfo.getAppPackageName());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinished(int sID, boolean success) {
                if (!success) {
                    // Print error details
                    Log.e(PKG_LOG_TAG, "Session failed: " + sID);
                    PackageInstaller.SessionInfo sessionInfo = pkgInstaller.getSessionInfo(sID);
                    if (sessionInfo != null) {
                        if (sessionInfo.isStaged())
                            Log.e(PKG_LOG_TAG, sessionInfo.getStagedSessionErrorCode() + " -- " + sessionInfo.getStagedSessionErrorMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Create package manager installation session
        int sessionId = pkgInstaller.createSession(params);
        PackageInstaller.Session session = pkgInstaller.openSession(sessionId);

        // Stream downloaded APK file to package manager session
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(apkFilePath);
        OutputStream out = session.openWrite("update_session", 0, -1);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
        int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
        while (bytesRead != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
        }

        // Close streams
        session.fsync(out);
        out.close();
        in.close();

        // Close session
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, sessionId, new Intent(ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE),0);
        session.commit(pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
        session.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output I get indicates a proper SessionID was created, but immediately after that 'getSessionInfo()' returns null. According to the official Android documentation, this indicate the SessionID in question does not exist. But how can that be when I'm in a callback handler for the session in question? Note this happens for all the callbacks, not just Create.

```
system_process W/PackageManager: installPackageLI
E/pkg-install-status: Session created: 676341822
E/pkg-install-status: Session does not exist: 676341822
E/pkg-install-status: Active Changed: 676341822, active=true
E/pkg-install-status: Progress changed: 676341822, progress=0.8
E/pkg-install-status: Progress changed: 676341822, progress=0.90000004
E/pkg-install-status: Session failed: 676341822
```

And here's the weird part - every now and then, sessionInfo is NOT null and the desired data is printed.